# Como expandir uma dataframe com base numa condiçao

Tags: python, dataframe, columns

Eu tenho a seguinte dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'left_bound' : ['1', '4', '10', '25'], 
    'right_bound' : ['3', '9', '24', '50'], 
    'code' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
})
```

E queria convertê-la para uma assim:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'bound' : ['1', '2','3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], 
    'code' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b','b','b','b','b','c'], 
})
```

Até 50 neste caso.

A ideia é ter uma sequência com todos os numeros inteiros desde o lower bound até ao upper bound nas rows e o code correspondente a esse número na coluna seguinte.

Obrigado!

Comment: Nobre, boa tarde! Creio que essa pergunta precisa ser melhor explicada. O que faz  1 2 3 ser a a a? O que faz 4 5 6 ser b b b? Abraço!

Comment: Boa tarde! Eu ao inicio tenho uma dataframe com 3 colunas, left_bound, right_bound e code. Neste caso, todos os números entre 1 e 3, inclusive, têm o code 'a'. Todos os numeros entre 4 e 9 têm o code 'b', etc. Ou seja, todos os numeros entre o left_bound e o right_bound têm aquele code associado. No entanto eu queria ter apenas uma coluna com todos os numeros entre o min da left_bound e o max da right_bound e outra com o code associado! Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

importando o pacote pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Criando o data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'left_bound' : ['1', '4', '10', '25'], 
    'right_bound' : ['3', '9', '24', '50'], 
    'code' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
})
```

Transformando as colunas em valores inteiros

```
df['left_bound'] = df['left_bound'].astype('int64')
df['right_bound'] = df['right_bound'].astype('int64')
```

Criando uma nova coluna capturando o range entre uma coluna e outra

```
df['bound'] = df.apply(lambda x : list(range(x['left_bound'],x['right_bound'] + 1)),axis = 1)
```

Excluindo as colunas desnecessárias

```
df.drop(columns=['left_bound','right_bound'], inplace = True)
```

Transformando as listas da coluna `bound` em linhas

```
df = df.explode('bound')
```

Modificando a ordem de apresentação das colunas

```
df = df[['bound','code']]
```

Imprimindo os 5 primeiros registros do data frame

```
df.head()
```

Saída:

```
    bound   code
0      1    a
0      2    a
0      3    a
1      4    b
1      5    b
```

---

Código:

```
df['left_bound'] = df['left_bound'].astype('int64')
df['right_bound'] = df['right_bound'].astype('int64')

df['bound'] = df.apply(lambda x : list(range(x['left_bound'],x['right_bound'] + 1)),axis = 1)
df.drop(columns=['left_bound','right_bound'], inplace = True)
df = df.explode('bound')

df = df[['bound','code']]
df.head()
```